# Removing a core runtime for Snapd program does not work

Tags: software-center, software-uninstall

I installed Snapd from the Software app then uninstalled it when the screen capture did not function.

An additional runtime environment component was installed alongside Snapd. When I try and remove it in the Software app, I am prompted for a password then nothing happens.

How do I manually remove this piece of software?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot remove it in this manner. It is required for snaps to work.

If you wish to remove it, you should remove all other snaps, then `apt purge` snapd. Then you can reboot and delete the `/snap` tree if you wish, which will get rid of the files for the core runtime package.

Comment: I had already run `sudo apt-get remove snapd` before trying to remove this core element. `sudo apt purge snapd` removed addition programs but did not remove the core file show in the screen shot. How do I delete a program tree? Thanks again for the help dobey!

Comment: Maybe the software center didn't update quickly enough, but the core element is no longer being shown (so the `purge` command worked!).
Thanks again @dobey!!

Comment: Well, _Software_ gets the list of available and installed snaps, from _snapd_ itself, so if it was stopped and removed, they wouldn't show up, but the installed snaps would likely still be on disk.